# Hibernate/Spring JPA findOne() calling update command

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, crud

I have a method to return an object array. The catalogVersion variable is tied to OECATVER entity. For some reason I cannot understand, when we return this Object[], the code calls an update query on OECATVER. I can't see anything that would cause that and it appears to happen immediately after this object is returned. The only queries I see performed in this method are findOne(id). That shouldn't cause an update, should it?

```
    public Object[] getPrefixCatalogVersion(String itemPrefix, int itemBusinessUnit) {
    CatalogVersion catalogVersion = null;
    String prefixReplacementReason = null;
    Object[] versionAndReason = new Object[2];

    CatalogPrefixKey prefixKey = new CatalogPrefixKey();
    prefixKey.setBusinessUnit(itemBusinessUnit);
    prefixKey.setCatalogPrefix(itemPrefix);
    CatalogPrefix catPrefix = catalogPrefixRepository.findOne(prefixKey);

    CatalogVersionKey versionKey = new CatalogVersionKey();
    versionKey.setBusinessUnit(catPrefix.getKey().getBusinessUnit());
    versionKey.setCatalogNumber(catPrefix.getCatalogNumber());
    versionKey.setCatalogVersion(catPrefix.getCatalogVersion());
    catalogVersion = catalogVersionRepository.findOne(versionKey);

    if (catalogVersion != null) {
        // We have the version, make sure it's still valid...
        // If it's not dead...
        if (!isCatalogDead(catalogVersion)) {
            // If it's active and not expired, add to the map.
            if (isCatalogActive(catalogVersion, itemBusinessUnit)) {
                if (!isCatalogExpired(catalogVersion)) {
                    // Do Nothing
                } else {
                    prefixReplacementReason = CommonConstants.PREFIX_REPLACEMENT_REASON_EXPIRED;
                }
            } else {
                prefixReplacementReason = CommonConstants.PREFIX_REPLACEMENT_REASON_NOT_ACTIVE;
            }
        } else {
            prefixReplacementReason = CommonConstants.PREFIX_REPLACEMENT_REASON_END_LIFE;
        }
    } else {
        prefixReplacementReason = CommonConstants.PREFIX_REPLACEMENT_REASON_INVALID;
    }

    versionAndReason[0] = catalogVersion;
    versionAndReason[1] = prefixReplacementReason;
    return versionAndReason;
}
```

These are the logs I see when running this method.

```
Hibernate: select catalogpre0_.BUSUNTNBR as BUSUNTNB1_41_0_, catalogpre0_.CATPFX as CATPFX2_41_0_, catalogpre0_.lstupdjob as lstupdjo3_41_0_, catalogpre0_.lstupdnbr as lstupdnb4_41_0_, catalogpre0_.lstupdpgm as lstupdpg5_41_0_, catalogpre0_.lstupdtsp as lstupdts6_41_0_, catalogpre0_.lstupdusr as lstupdus7_41_0_, catalogpre0_.CATNBR as CATNBR8_41_0_, catalogpre0_.CATVER as CATVER9_41_0_ from OECATPFX catalogpre0_ where catalogpre0_.BUSUNTNBR=? and catalogpre0_.CATPFX=?
Hibernate: select catalogver0_.BUSUNTNBR as BUSUNTNB1_43_0_, catalogver0_.CATNBR as CATNBR2_43_0_, catalogver0_.CATVER as CATVER3_43_0_, catalogver0_.lstupdjob as lstupdjo4_43_0_, catalogver0_.lstupdnbr as lstupdnb5_43_0_, catalogver0_.lstupdpgm as lstupdpg6_43_0_, catalogver0_.lstupdtsp as lstupdts7_43_0_, catalogver0_.lstupdusr as lstupdus8_43_0_, catalogver0_.CATVERDSC as CATVERDS9_43_0_, catalogver0_.CURCATPCG as CURCATP10_43_0_, catalogver0_.EFFDAT as EFFDAT11_43_0_, catalogver0_.EXPDAT as EXPDAT12_43_0_, catalogver0_.PSDSALFLG as PSDSALF13_43_0_ from OECATVER catalogver0_ where catalogver0_.BUSUNTNBR=? and catalogver0_.CATNBR=? and catalogver0_.CATVER=?
Hibernate: select catalog0_.BUSUNTNBR as BUSUNTNB1_40_0_, catalog0_.CATNBR as CATNBR2_40_0_, catalog0_.lstupdjob as lstupdjo3_40_0_, catalog0_.lstupdnbr as lstupdnb4_40_0_, catalog0_.lstupdpgm as lstupdpg5_40_0_, catalog0_.lstupdtsp as lstupdts6_40_0_, catalog0_.lstupdusr as lstupdus7_40_0_, catalog0_.CATEOLDAT as CATEOLDA8_40_0_, catalog0_.CATNAM as CATNAM9_40_0_, catalog0_.CATTHMCLF as CATTHMC10_40_0_, catalog0_.CATTYPCLF as CATTYPC11_40_0_ from OECATMST catalog0_ where catalog0_.BUSUNTNBR=? and catalog0_.CATNBR=?
Hibernate: select orderentry0_.BUSUNTNBR as BUSUNTNB1_6_0_, orderentry0_.lstupdjob as lstupdjo2_6_0_, orderentry0_.lstupdnbr as lstupdnb3_6_0_, orderentry0_.lstupdpgm as lstupdpg4_6_0_, orderentry0_.lstupdtsp as lstupdts5_6_0_, orderentry0_.lstupdusr as lstupdus6_6_0_, orderentry0_.AREMLPMP as AREMLPMP7_6_0_, orderentry0_.ALWNTLACT as ALWNTLAC8_6_0_, orderentry0_.ATOASNCGY as ATOASNCG9_6_0_, orderentry0_.AVLJOBSFY as AVLJOBS10_6_0_, orderentry0_.CASQTYLMT as CASQTYL11_6_0_, orderentry0_.COPITMFLG as COPITMF12_6_0_, orderentry0_.CREPSPCUS as CREPSPC13_6_0_, orderentry0_.VRLCATNBR as VRLCATN14_6_0_, orderentry0_.VRLCATPFX as VRLCATP15_6_0_, orderentry0_.VRLCATVER as VRLCATV16_6_0_, orderentry0_.VRLKEYCOD as VRLKEYC17_6_0_, orderentry0_.DFTQTEDAY as DFTQTED18_6_0_, orderentry0_.DSPOFRPRV as DSPOFRP19_6_0_, orderentry0_.DUPORD as DUPORD20_6_0_, orderentry0_.EMLPMPFLG as EMLPMPF21_6_0_, orderentry0_.EMPKEYCOD as EMPKEYC22_6_0_, orderentry0_.HGHPRCCHK as HGHPRCC23_6_0_, orderentry0_.HGHQTYCHK as HGHQTYC24_6_0_, orderentry0_.IPRCNFAMT as IPRCNFA25_6_0_, orderentry0_."Jobber Safety Threshold" as Jobber26_6_0_, orderentry0_.MAXQTEDAY as MAXQTED27_6_0_, orderentry0_.PFXRQDFLG as PFXRQDF28_6_0_, orderentry0_.PRCOVRCHK as PRCOVRC29_6_0_, orderentry0_.PRCGRCPED as PRCGRCP30_6_0_, orderentry0_.ORDRSNCLF as ORDRSNC31_6_0_, orderentry0_.RQROPBFLG as RQROPBF32_6_0_, orderentry0_.SPLTABRQD as SPLTABR33_6_0_, orderentry0_.USEKEYCGY as USEKEYC34_6_0_, orderentry0_.WGTLMT as WGTLMT35_6_0_ from COBRLORD orderentry0_ where orderentry0_.BUSUNTNBR=?
Hibernate: update OECATVER set lstupdjob=?, lstupdnbr=?, lstupdpgm=?, lstupdtsp=?, lstupdusr=?, CATVERDSC=?, CURCATPCG=?, EFFDAT=?, EXPDAT=?, PSDSALFLG=? where BUSUNTNBR=? and CATNBR=? and CATVER=?
```

**Update:**

```
public boolean isCatalogDead(CatalogVersion catalogVersion) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    CatalogKey key = new CatalogKey();
    key.setBusinessUnit(catalogVersion.getKey().getBusinessUnit());
    key.setCatalogNumber(catalogVersion.getKey().getCatalogNumber());

    Catalog catalog = catalogRepository.findOne(key);

    if (catalog != null) {
        Calendar endOfLifeDate = catalog.getEndOfLifeDate();
        if (today.after(endOfLifeDate)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public boolean isCatalogActive(CatalogVersion catalogVersion, int itemBusinessUnit) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Check to see if the catalog is still available
    Calendar fromDate = catalogVersion.getEffectiveDate();
    int gracePeriodDays = companyService.getPricingGracePeriodDays(itemBusinessUnit);
    fromDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, gracePeriodDays * -1);
    if (today.before(fromDate)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean isCatalogExpired(CatalogVersion catalogVersion) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar toDate = catalogVersion.getExpirationDate();
    if (today.after(toDate)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: wow... what is inside: isCatalogDead; isCatalogActive; isCatalogExpired? if it's inside transactional any change would also be saved to db, regardless of you calling .save(entity) or not.

Comment: just so you know, you should refactor this... also, naming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the issue. The issue was in the isCatalogActive() method, see below. When I was updating the fromDate variable, it was updating the date in catalogVersion as well. I changed it to making a new Calendar object for fromDate and setting the time to be the same as catalogVersion.getEffectiveDate(); and worked with the fromDate that way.

**Old Way**

```
public boolean isCatalogActive(CatalogVersion catalogVersion, int itemBusinessUnit) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Check to see if the catalog is still available
    Calendar fromDate = catalogVersion.getEffectiveDate();
    int gracePeriodDays = companyService.getPricingGracePeriodDays(itemBusinessUnit);
    fromDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, gracePeriodDays * -1);
    if (today.before(fromDate)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**NEW WAY**

```
public boolean isCatalogActive(CatalogVersion catalogVersion, int itemBusinessUnit) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Check to see if the catalog is still available
    Calendar fromDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDate.setTime(catalogVersion.getEffectiveDate().getTime());
    int gracePeriodDays = companyService.getPricingGracePeriodDays(itemBusinessUnit);
    fromDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, gracePeriodDays * -1);
    if (today.before(fromDate)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```